# Extracting the send context Data Extension fields using SSJS

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, ssjs

I am trying to extract the send context Data Extension from an email thats being sent by placing the following code in the email itself:

```
<script runat="server">
Platform.Load("Core", "1.1.1");    
    try {      
      var DEtoCopy = DataExtension.Init("test_extension_101"); // will be using %%_DataSourceName%% to make this dynamic
      var jsonArray = DEtoCopy.Fields.Retrieve();
      Write("   DEtoCopy: " + Stringify(DEtoCopy));
      Write("   jsonArray: " + Stringify(jsonArray));

    } catch (ex) {
        Write("An error has occurred: " + Stringify(ex));
        Write("   DEtoCopy: " + Stringify(DEtoCopy));
        Write("   jsonArray: " + Stringify(jsonArray));
    }
</script>
```

I plan to store the values using AMPScript later but right now I just want to see if the attributes are actually retrieved, and it doesn't look like they are. When the email is sent to me I get the following try/catch error:

> An error has occurred: {"message":"Object expected:
>   Retrieve","jintException":"Jint.Native.JsException: Exception of type
>   'Jint.Native.JsException' was thrown.\r\n at
>   Jint.ExecutionVisitor.Visit(MethodCall methodCall)\r\n at
>   Jint.ExecutionVisitor.Visit(MemberExpression expression)\r\n at
>   Jint.ExecutionVisitor.Visit(VariableDeclarationStatement
>   statement)\r\n at Jint.ExecutionVisitor.Visit(BlockStatement
>   statement)\r\n at Jint.ExecutionVisitor.Visit(TryStatement
>   statement)","description":"Jint.Native.JsException: Object expected:
>   Retrieve\r\nException of type 'Jint.Native.JsException' was thrown. -
>   from Jint\r\n\r\n"} jsonArray: null

Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Have you verified that `test_extension_101` is a real DE in your current BU? The issue is that there was no Object for the `Fields.Retrieve()` to pull from, which is what caused the error. This means the issue needs to be in the declaration of the `DEtoCopy` var.

Comment: Also Fields.Retrieve will provide the DE's field names, not the individual values of these fields. Are you trying to pull all the available attributes (from the sendable DE) for each person?

Comment: So for this piece of code I'm only trying to retrieve the actual fields (and their properties). In the grand scheme of things what I'm trying to do is copy the Data Extension, both its fields and the values (for each send) to store in a JSON string in a Log object so I can recreate later.

Comment: So rerunning the code with a debug on the `DEtoCopy` returns `null`. The Data Extension is definitely there, and both the name and external key are as labelled in my code.

Comment: I think the issue may be that CORE SSJS can not be run inside emails, only in landing pages/ Cloud pages and applications/Script Activities.   "Core library server-side JavaScript functions allow you to use standard JSON and JavaScript functionality to interact with Marketing Cloud. Platform objects can function within landing pages and applications."  (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_coreLibraryFunctions.htm)

Comment: Would there be any other way we can retrieve the Data Extension (fields and values) within the email context?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88423/discussion-between-gortonington-and-deployment-failure).